# How can I remove a sublist of a list in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

I want to deliver the first seven cards of a deck of cards. A card is a string, and the player and the deck are lists of strings.

I need to do a function that:

- Append the first seven strings of a list of strings (deck of cards) to another list of string (player).
- Remove the first seven strings of a list of strings (deck of cards).
- Return the player with the new cards and the deck of cards without those cards.

I am new in OCaml and I can't do it with loops or recursion.

The code:

```
let sevencardsto player deck =
  for i = 1 to 7 do
  player = List. hd deck :: player ;
  deck = List.tl deck ; 
  done ;
  (player,deck) ;;
```

Comment: You should start by showing the code that you attempted before trying to get other people to do your homework.

Comment: Yes i forget  @EdgarAroutiounian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code actually compiles (after the fix of a silly typo), but you should see a warning:

```
File "pepe.ml", line 3, characters 2-33:
Warning 10: this expression should have type unit.
```

Do *NOT* underestimate this warning.  ML is a functional language and all the variables are immutable.

```
player = List.hd deck :: player
```

does not reassign a new value to the variable `player` like imperative programming.  It compares the values of the left and the right hand sides of `=` and returns a boolean, then this boolean is discarded by `;`.  The compiler warns this worrying you are doing something wrong.  The same happens at line 4.  Your function just returns the original `player` and `deck` unchanged.

Your task here can be separated the following subtasks:

- A function `split_at : 'a list -> int -> 'a list * 'a list`, which splits a list into two at the position of the given number.  You can separate the first 7 cards of the deck and the rest with this function.
- Append the splitted 7 cards to `player`. This is simply done by `@`, list append:

`let ncardsto player deck n =
  let n_cards, rest = split_at deck n in
  (n_cards @ player, rest)`

Implementing `split_at` function is a basic exercise of recursion + list.

Ah, you CANNOT use recursion NOR loop?  I see no point in your exercise...  I just give you a hint:

`match xs with
| x1::x2::xs' ->`

This code gets the first two elements and `xs'` is bound to the rest.